# Android - How to display a spinner with value but display a different one

Tags: java, android, spinner

For my Android app, I need to use a spinner which displays a XML tree. This tree is necesarry for the user to understand the level of the value he can select.

Here is a picture of what I have right now:
[image]

As you can see, I've put some little '>' and some spaces to simulate the tree. What I want now, is when the user select an entry, to display the value without those symbols.

Today, the spinner displays the value like that:
[image]

THe word is "   > Supermarket" but what I want is "Supermarket", and only that. Is there a way to modifiy the selected value displayed by the spinner but not the list?

I hope you'll be able to help me.

Regards.

V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I used if someone needs it:

First, replace your spinner by the folowing portion of code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">    

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/custom_spinner"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fake_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_spinner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fake_text"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a new XML file in your drawable folder named `custom_spinner.xml` and puts that code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item
         android:state_focused="true" 
         android:state_pressed="false" 
         android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_normal" />

</selector>
```

Download those two pictures and add them into your drawable folder (`spinner_pressed.9.png` and `spinner_normal.9.png`):

[image: spinner_pressed.9.png]
[image: spinner_normal.9.png]

In your activity, add the following variables:

```
private Spinner spinner;
private Button fake_btn;
private TextView fake_text;
```

In the onCreate method, add:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
fake_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fake_btn);
fake_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fake_text);

fake_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        spinner.performClick();
    }
});

spinner_manual.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id)
    {           
        String value = (String) spinner.getItemAtPosition(position);
        fake_text.setText(value);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView) {}  
});
```

There you are, it should work.

Comment: this code is lil bit incomplete, you didn't added the code of replacing the value as Vipin suggested. Still i got my problem solve by this, so +1 to both of you :)

Answer (score 4):

you can do this with the idea that

make your spinner invisible put an textView behind the spinner
set TextView text to spinner selected item with

```
textView.settext(spinner.getSelectedItem().replace(">","").trim()));
```

dont forget to put spinner over the textView otherwise you will not get spinner click
event

Comment: Thanks, but how to do the same thing if I want to display the spinner shape?

Comment: its easy just set the background of you text view to spinner image

Comment: you need the spinner image which you can get easily

Comment: I was thinking that every android distrib has its own design. So it will be very difficult to have only one spinner image :s

Comment: so you set your own a custom image matching with application theme