# Android - Defining value displayed within spinner (different from selected value)

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a spinner which contains dynamic data which is displayed over 2 lines. What I require help with is dislaying only part of the spinners value (ItemArrayName[i]) within the spinner text box.

To calrify in the popup when the spinner is clicked, I require the full text, however when the item has been select I only require the item name.

e.g. 
Within the App:
Item Name

Within the spinner selection pop out:
Item Name
Atk = 10, Def = 10

```
Java Code:

ArrayList<String> ItemArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();  
for(int i = 0; i < ItemArrayName.length; i++)
{
    ItemArrayList.add(ItemArrayName[i] + "\nAtk = " + String.valueOf(ItemArrayAtk[i]) + ", Def = " + String.valueOf(ItemArrayDef[i]));
}

Spinner spnItem = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.UseItem);
ArrayAdapter<String> adpItem = new ArrayAdapter<String> (context, R.layout.spinnerrow, ItemArrayList);
spnItem.setAdapter(adpItem);
spnItem.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{   
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) 
    {
        //String city = "The item is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a Hashtable to map what you display in the spinner to your more detailed popup string?

EDIT:
Here's a primitive and possibly non compiling modification to your code using a hashtable as described:

```
// EDIT #1: Create a hashtable to lookup stuff:
final Hashtable<String, String> vals = new Hashtable<String, String>();

      for(int i = 0; i < ItemArrayName.length; i++)
      {
         vals.put(ItemArrayName[i], ItemArrayName[i] + "\nAtk = " + String.valueOf(ItemArrayAtk[i]) + ", Def = " + String.valueOf(ItemArrayDef[i]));
      }

      Spinner spnItem = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.UseItem);
      // EDIT #2: Extract the array of hash keys to show in your list:
      ArrayAdapter<String> adpItem = new ArrayAdapter<String> context, R.layout.spinnerrow, vals.keySet().toArray(new String[vals.size()]));
      spnItem.setAdapter(adpItem);
      spnItem.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
      {
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3)
         {
            // EDIT #3: retrieve the full string from the hashtable using "get":
            String city = "The item is " + vals.get(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
         {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
      });
```

Comment: Could you please refer me to a good tutorial or provide me with sample code please, as I am new to both android and java development.

Comment: Hi Nick, just tried that unfortunetly  it does not work, it simply adds the 'ItemArrayName[i] into both sections of the spinner. Any other idea? Thanks

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking - i thought you just wanted to use the full text in your toast call.  As far as I know there is no "clean" way to do this, but it looks like you can get the desired effect by following the instructions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972771/android-how-to-display-a-spinner-with-value-but-display-a-different-one

Comment: Followed that link and that does the job, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping your short text to your long text.

```
HashMap<String,String> itemValues = new HashMap<String,String>();
itemValues.add("short text","the full long text that pops up when item is selected");

String longTextToDisplay = itemValues.get(currentSelectedShortText);
```

Of course this is a simplified example and this could be made more flexible, but this is the basic idea. You're just saying "this short text goes with this long text."

Comment: As per Nicks answer, I have tried implementing this, however this simply showed me the abbreviated version in both sections of the spinner, have you got any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everyone makes this much harder than it has to be.  If the data is displayed in the spinner already, you can grab it from there without having to refer to the backing data.

Assuming you have a LinearLayout containing the two textviews (call them tv1 and tv2) as your row layout for the spinner, and you want the value of tv2, you could do this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3)  
{ 
    TextView tvResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(r.id.tv2);
    String city = tvResult.getText().toString();
}
```

**EDIT**

I misunderstood your question... that I know of there is no way to make the closed spinner box display text different from the actual selection within the spinner using an ArrayAdapter.  If there is, I'd be interested in seeing/reading about it.

I can think of a way to do it with a CursorAdapter, but as I said above, I can't think of any way to manage it for an ArrayAdapter.

The one option I can think of would be to find the spinner class in the android source, copy it out and modify it to make your own spinner class that is capable of such a function.

Comment: Unless I'm completely misunderstanding, the issue is that the data is not displayed in the spinner already; only an abbreviated form is displayed there.

Comment: My understanding is that he has the full display in the drop-down and wants an abbreviated form in the closed textbox.  Guess the OP needs to clarify.

Comment: Yes Barak is correct, I require the full text displayed when the spinner is opened and only part of the text when it has been closed. If it is not possible in a spinner what other ways can I create a multiple selection drop down with this type of functionality. Thanks

Comment: Where is your data in the array coming from?  A database?  If that is the case I think I might have a solution for you using a CursorAdapter...

Comment: Unfortunetly not, at the moment it is being stored in an ArrayList(S1 x String & 2 x int) with items etc constantly being added to it as the user progress through the game picking up more items.