# How to float multiple Views over a single View in Android

Tags: android, android-view, floating

I am trying to figure out a way to float multiple Views over another one, probably either a `ListView`, or `GridLayout`. Almost all questions answer with `FrameLayout`, unfortunately that doesn't work because it was made to float a single View, so that rules it out of the question. I was thinking of using `RelativeLayout`, but I am having trouble figuring out how to make it work with that. Has anybody been able to figure out a way to do this? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Floating, means just statically placed Views over another View? If so, just define xml and on the same level of tree and specify margins and/or paddings. If you need animation use setX and/or setY properties to draw floating View where you need.

Answer (score 3):

Later children in a `RelativeLayout` float over earlier children.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/big"
        android:textSize="120dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/small"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second `Button` floats over top of the first `Button`, giving you:

[image: big under small]

Here is the complete sample project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Containers/RelativeOverlap.

Comment: If, lets say, instead of Button Big, its a GridLayout, and then the Button small, is instead a LinearLayout, would whatever I put in LinearLayout dynamically also float above the GridLayout?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow what you are asking, it seems like the solutions posted for this seemingly unrelated question might work for your application as well:

[Android - How to display a spinner with value but display a different one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972771/android-how-to-display-a-spinner-with-value-but-display-a-different-one)